# Why does Windows have a built-in JavaScript parser?

Tags: windows-7, javascript

JavaScript is a client-side web scripting language, and cannot run on its own.

Today I was separating JavaScript into its own file for a website that I'm building, and I noticed that Windows has a JavaScript parser built-in:

[image]

Why does Windows have a JavaScript parser built-in?

Comment: Windows has a built-in JavaScript parser because Microsoft decided to build one.  I am not sure the community can give an actual reason beyond the fact, Windows has one, because it has one.

Comment: JavaScript is not just restricted to web pages. It has many uses outside of web development as well. They're [listed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Uses_outside_Web_pages). Also, Windows has a JScript parser.